# find unique items based on date column

Tags: mysql

I need to find unique items based on date column. I tried to group the data together, but am not getting the desired result.

In the below sample i need to find the new entry i.e."New Company" seen on date 27th July because it does not exists on 16th July. I have thousand such rows and various dates.
The table contains issues seen on an Operating system datewise. I need to find the new issues a particular company is hitting. Pls help!

```
mysql> select * from testdata;
+------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| date       | os_ver     | account_name    | count |
+------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| 2018-07-16 | 22.345-595 | Company AA1     |     2 |
| 2018-07-16 | 22.346-596 | Company BB1     |     1 |
| 2018-07-16 | 22.346-596 | Company CC1     |     2 |
| 2018-07-27 | 22.346-595 | Company AA1     |     1 |
| 2018-07-27 | 22.346-596 | Company BB1     |     2 |
| 2018-07-27 | 22.346-596 | New Company     |     1 |
| 2018-07-27 | 22.346-596 | Company CC1     |     1 |
+------------+----------------+----------------------
```

I tried the below, but it's not showing the unique item:

```
SELECT * FROM `testdata` group by timestamp order by timestamp DESC
```

Comment: please share sample data and your expected output that would be helpful to guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear. However if you are trying to find the earliest date for the first occurence of each account name, then see the following query.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN test t1 
  ON t.date > t1.date
  AND t.account_name = t1.account_name
WHERE t1.date IS NULL;
```

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfec03/7) demonstrating the query with your sample data.

Alternatively, if you want to find all account names that occur only once, then see the following query.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
GROUP BY t.account_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfec03/12) demonstrating the query with your sample data.

Comment: Yes the query is returning the unique entry wonderfully. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

your question is not much clear but i guess you need below something

```
select date,os_ver,account_name,count(*) from testdata
group by date,os_ver,account_name
```

Comment: Thanks Zaynul.The below method by Fubar is returning the unique rows, in this case "| 2018-07-27 | 22.346-596 | New Company     |     1 |".